# How to make a contact form that sends me mail via Mandrill on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, contact-form, mandrill

I have a contact form

```
<div align="center">
  <h3>Send A message to Us</h3>

  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <div class= "hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

connected to a controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

and a model

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  #include MailForm::Delivery

  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Message from visitor at mydomain.com",
      :to => "charlie@mydomain.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

which is supposed to send me mail from a contact form. Here are my production and development.rb's (which are the same):

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 25, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
    :user_name => "myusername",
    :password  => "mypassword", # SMTP password is any valid API key
    :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
    :domain => 'mydomain.com', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
  }
```

Except, of course, I have my real credentials and domain in the appropriate places. When I try to create a contact via my localhost:3000/contacts form, I get this error:
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in ContactsController#create
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
Line 9     if @contact.deliver

I've googled around but I can't figure it out. I've followed directions from [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks) and a variety of other places that now I can't remember. How can I fix my contact form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`authentication` should not be a string. Try this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port           => "587",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => "myusername",
    :password       => "mypassword",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error about "Username and Password not accepted" in the @contact.deliver section.